# Traffic Control in OpenStack Neutron with either TC or OpenVSwitch

Tags: traffic-shaping, qos, tc, openvswitch, openstack-neutron

As far as I know, QoS in OpenStack Neutron is still under development and not production-ready (I could be wrong on this point though, shout at me if so...), but we are required to implement traffic control in our cloud environment. Hence, we are thinking to utilize traditional tool like tc, or built-in QoS functions in OpenVSwitch which is used by Neutron.

So, the first question: To achieve traffic control in Neutron, is there any outstanding keynotes/speech/howto/tutorial/idea-sharing available out there that we could refer to? URLs are very much welcome

The second question: we have tried following setups:

- TC TBF algorithm works on L3 router agents, although only for egress traffic on external interface (the one facing public network). This means that we could only limit uploading bandwidth.
- OVS QoS policies do NOT work at all! We are suspecting that whether OVS QoS supports virtual device at all?

If you happen to come across the same problem, we would appreciate any ideas!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: When I did it (Admittedly about 18 months ago) we pushed out TC configs to all the compute nodes so that the QoS was done on the leaves of the network rather than the core - this worked pretty well and was a requirement as our storage and data traffic was sharing the same 10gb NIC

Comment: @GeraintJones thans for your comment! We would like to limit aggregated bandwidth shared by all instances in one tenant (and these instances may reside in several physical compute node). So how do you distribute the bandwidth to leaf node to achieve a controlled total bandwidth? Thanks!